# Error : Source Model not found while creating a new attribute in customer entity

Tags: magento-1.9, sql

I wrote a simple sql upgrade script to add a custom attribute to the customer table.
My script :

```
<?php
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute('customer', 'whatsapp_active', array(
    'type'       => 'static',
    'input'      => 'boolean',
    'label'      => 'Is Customer Active',
    'default' => '1',
    'visible' => true,
    'required' => false,
    'user_defined' => true,
));

Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
    ->getAttribute('customer', 'whatsapp_active')
    ->setData('used_in_forms', array('adminhtml_customer'))
    ->save();

$installer->endSetup();
```

I get the error  :

```
a:5:{i:0;s:57:"Source model "" not found for attribute "whatsapp_status"";i:1;s:2983:"#0 /var/www/html/fresh/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php(387): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Source model ""...')
#1 /var/www/html/fresh/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(201): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract->getSource()
```

**Now, even when I have removed the file, then also I get the same error.**

PS : I have changed, my `core_resource` table code `customer_setup` versions accordingly.

So, what is the thing which I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can try Following way..

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();


$installer->addAttribute("customer", "whatsapp_active",  array(
    "type"     => "int",
    "backend"  => "",
    "label"    => "Is Customer Active",
    "input"    => "select",
    "source"   => "eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean",
    "visible"  => true,
    "required" => false,
    "default" => "",
    "frontend" => "",
    "unique"     => false,
    "note"       => ""

    ));

        $attribute   = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer", "whatsapp_active");


$used_in_forms=array();

$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
        $attribute->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
        ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
        ->setData("is_system", 0)
        ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
        ->setData("is_visible", 1)
        ->setData("sort_order", 100)
        ;
        $attribute->save();



$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: But how to remove the error, as I mentioned in the answer that the error is still happening even when I removed the file. Is there anything that I need to do?
PS : I am able to remove the error by deleting the attribute. Thanks

Comment: you need to var folder rename and may be this code is working because i have checked my side and created attribute